# How to reinstall OS X after changing hard drive?

Tags: macos, mac

I have problem with my **MacBook Pro**. The hard drive was broken, and I installed new one.Totaly empty, without EFI and everything.

I can not install OS X on it.

I only able to launch "Internet recovery" (holding option key during startup). So it is possible to run Disk Utility and Terminal. When I try to install system from this recovery, I have error;

I also unable to boot from flash-drive, pressing C key. But, I can mount flash drive from Internet Recovery and try to start setup. I have another error "**This copy of the Install OS X Mountain Lion can't be verified. It may have been corrupted or tampered during downloading**". I tried to use different versions, but error is the same.

What can I do to start my mac?

Comment: Have you tried to contact Apple Support?

Comment: I think, they can offer to use original boot DVD, but I can't find it. Or to visit service and pay money ;)

Comment: Assuming you have your installation DVD, you can use your DVD drive, try to boot from it, format the hard disk drive to HFS, and then install OSX.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, but I haven't this DVD. Please read my post again. I can also format hard drive from recovery mode. Problem is not in it.

Comment: Just trying to help. I'm not familiar with the new versions of OSX starting from Snow Leopard, so I thought the process was similar.

Comment: How are you writing the image to the USB?  Sounds like the issue comes down to that.

Comment: Are there some specific error messages when you try to install OS X in Internet Recovery mode? Have you tried using [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1433)?

Answer (score 0):

I found in internet just "InstallESD.dmg" image, and with this file I repaired computer.
Very easy :)

Thanks for everyone!